# How to move a SCNNode in the direction it is pointing at after an rotation is applied

Tags: rotation, swift3, scenekit, trigonometry

My dilemma is this:
I have a spaceship positioned somewhere in space between stars and planets. The camera is added as a child of the spaceshipNode and you always look at the back of the spaceship (raised a few units above).
I use CoreMotion to rotate the spaceship like this:

```
    func startMonitoringMotion() {
    self.motionManager?.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main, withHandler: { (data, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }

        let attitude: CMAttitude = data.attitude
        self.ship.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(Float(attitude.roll - M_PI_2), Float(attitude.yaw), Float(attitude.pitch))
    })
}
```

and the rotation works as expected.

Now I want to move the spaceship in the direction it is facing but I have no clue how to do it. I have tried different approaches but I have failed miserably.

I have searched this forum countless times for several days but with no luck.
I hope someone can point me (and my spaceship) in the right direction.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that the easiest way to do this is to grab the third row of the node's `worldTransform` property, which corresponds to its z-forward axis.

```
func getZForward(node: SCNNode) -> SCNVector3 {
    return SCNVector3(node.worldTransform.m31, node.worldTransform.m32, node.worldTransform.m33)
}

ship.position += getZForward(ship) * speed // nb scalar multiply requires overload of * func
// if node has a physics body, you might need to use the presentationNode, eg:
// getZForward(ship.presentationNode)
// though you probably don't want to be directly modifying the position of a node with a physics body
```

See the discussion here [Getting direction that SCNNode is facing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26824759/getting-direction-that-scnnode-is-facing/37801146#37801146)

### iOS 11 update

iOS 11 adds handy convenience functions for getting the orientation of a node. In this case the `worldForward` property is the one you want. Also, all of the properties on `SCNNode` that return `SCNVector` and matrix types now have versions that return simd types. Because simd already has overloads for the arithmetic operators, you no longer need to add sets of arithmetic overrides for the `SCNVector` and `SCNMatrix` types.

So we can get rid of out `getZForward` method above, and just have the line:

```
ship.simdPosition += ship.simdWorldFront * speed
```

Comment: hi and thank you so much for you input. A few days ago I found the discussion where you suggested the same solution and I've been working on that combined with CoreMotion to control the ship. I wanted to wait marking your answer as 'the answer' until I was certain that it was the correct solution for me....and now I think it is, so thank you so very much.

Comment: @Sanxion can you please post your CoreMotion solution?

Comment: yay SIMD and easy accessors!

Comment: @OliverD - thank you so much for taking time to update your answer. I ended up taking time away for the project but I will give it a go again now based on your new information.

Comment: @user287474 - Hi there, I am sorry I did not see your question before now. I ended up taking some time away from my spaceship project but I will start working on it again. As soon as I have a working solution again I will post the relevant code.